# Probably a bug in computing user reputation

Tags: support, reputation

I had 22997 points this morning on stackoverflow. I answered a question and earned 25 points (+1 and answer accept). My profile says I earned 25 points today, but my reputation is 23012, which means I only earned 15 points. 
My profile: https://stackoverflow.com/users/391554/dan

The question I answered: [AChartEngine - Lock an Axis when zooming out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556168/achartengine-lock-an-axis-when-zooming-out)

A screenshot of my recent activity showing +15 for today, but +25 for the question I answered today.

[image]

Any thoughts?

**EDIT:** I checked the /reputation and results are interesting:

```
-- 2013-10-22 rep +40   = 22972     
 1  19543188 (15)
 2  12975943 (10)
-- 2013-10-23 rep +25   = 22997     
 2  19558247 (10)
 1  19558247 (15)
 2  19558247 (10)
-- 2013-10-24 rep +35   = 23032     

** rep today: 35
** rep this week (2013-10-20 - 2013-10-26): 100
** rep this month (2013-10-01 - 2013-10-31): 340
** rep this quarter (2013-10-01 - 2013-12-31): 340
** rep this year (2013-01-01 - 2013-12-31): 10176
** rep from bonuses: 100
** total rep 23032 :)
```

Interesting because right now the displayed reputation is 23022.

Comment: select show removed posts at the bottom of your http://stackoverflow.com/users/391554/dan?tab=reputation

Comment: okay now is it showing 23022..???

Comment: @DipeshParmar No, It because of one more upvote

Comment: It showed 23032 for a second and got down to 23022 then. That's because it got one more upvote.

Comment: @Dan and that was me who gave you +1..

Comment: @DipeshParmar Ok so what??, you matching the calculation, this is not the time, Still he not get 10 rep

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your reputation tab after selecting "show removed posts"?

Comment: Sounds good. I will just stop using meta. Cheers!

Comment: @Dan [meta-tag:bug] questions like this tend to attract downvotes on meta.  A good bug report should also include some idea on what's going on.  You seem unwilling to assist in the troubleshooting by getting aggressive with him056's request.  In the end, this is very likely not a bug, but actually a [meta-tag:support] question to understand how/why your reputation changed.

Comment: +1 because it appears something weird did happen. Looks like people here find it too "picky" to meddle over meager 10 points especially considering you have more than 20K, hence the downvotes.

Comment: Since you are not replying me, I am giving you an advice. Go to http://stackoverflow.com/reputation. Here you can audit your reputation. It's a nice hidden feature.

Comment: @hims056 Check the updated question.

Comment: @Dan - Click on "Trigger Reputation Recalc" to recalculate your reputation. But you can do it once a day.

Comment: @hims056 I have no idea where that button is.

Comment: @Dan - At the bottom of the page in http://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: OK, that fixed the inconsistency or usage error of my part. I got 6 downvotes for calling it a "bug".

Comment: Come on, you can do better than -7.

Answer (score 6):

> I had 22997 points this morning on stackoverflow

It's not clear when "This morning" was and when it occurred in relation to your positive reputation events, however timing of events can be important as some Net 0 reputation changes that occur on the same UTC day are not captured.  Some examples are:

- You received an upvote on a post and that same user later removed his upvote before midnight
- Someone accepted your answer on a question and then decided to unaccept in it the same day, it will not be recorded.

The reason is that these events are treated like they never existed.

So if received an upvote on a post today before seeing your 22997 rep this morning, and that voter chose to undo his vote later in the day, then it could explain why it looks like 10 rep mysteriously disappeared.

Ultimately if you just want to see what your actual reputation is, you can visit your reputation page @ `/reputation` on any site (so for Stack Overflow, it would be https://stackoverflow.com/reputation.  This is a daily blow-by-blow summary for every bit a positive & negative rep that occurred and when.  It still won't show individual changes that doesn't exist anymore (like for deleted users, deleted posts, or Net 0 rep days), but it will let you see how things looked on given days and where the discontinuity is coming from.

And if that page doesn't agree with the rep you are seeing on the site, then you can click the "Trigger Reputation Recalc" bottom of the page and that will recalcuate your reputation.  This is almost unnecessary to do anymore as the rep system does a pretty good job updating itself with events, but there are cases where it does get skewed.

In my observations, deletions and quick vote changes tend to confuse the live rep calculation, and since it is cached, it can take a while to get sorted out.  Just speculating as to what happened, but it is possible a post in which you had an answer with 1 upvote was deleted and then undeleted, or a quick upvote/unupvote/upvote occurred on one of your posts, and that caused +10 to get lost.  Forcing a reputation recalculation like you did will force the cached value to update.

Answer (score 3):

It must be because one of your post with +1 is removed today

Please check the box **`show removed posts`**

[image]

Comment: @Dan check my comment

Comment: @Dan its on your reputation page at bottom left. Thanks Bala

Comment: I checked that and I see no change for today.

Comment: @Dan may be its because moderator has deleted any user to whoes question you have answered and got +1 vote

Comment: @DipeshParmar in such case it will show "user was removed" event.